# Как работать с двумя ветками одновременно(гитхаб)?

Tags: git

Пример:я сделал форк проекта Ф. Получил задание А и сделал три коммита и пуша А1,А2 и А3.
Потом получил задание В-нужно сделать коммиты и пушы на начальный Ф,допустим,В1,В2 и В3.Потом сделать ещё коммит и пуш А4.И в итоге предоставить два пул реквеста : 1)Ф->А1->А2->А3->А4 2)Ф->В1->В2->В3. 
Как это сделать ,если можно подробно : команда (что делает).

Спасибо.

Comment: Ух...

Мой вам совет, скачайте вот [эту][1] книгу и прочтите с 1 по 4 главу(для начала)
  
  [1]: https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/downloads/GArik/progit/progit.ru.pdf

Comment: Самый распространенный и самый бесполезный ответ,зачем он здесь?

Comment: Тяжелый случай, но если вы бы воспользовались моим советом, то, о ужас, обнаружили бы ответ на свой вопрос, а заодно и подтянули бы знания по работе с СКВ.(или просто могли воспользоваться поиском по PDF)

Тут вам не школа("неполный ответ" ха-ха-ха), @misha-nesterenko потратил свое личное время набрав этот ответ и никто ничем вам тут не обязан.

При этом вы я явно некомпетентны в области IT (повидал уже таких мнимых "гениев").

Однако я надеюсь, что вы осилите **3 главу** от первоисточника, а не будите дальше мучить людей своим неумением читать.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Кого я будИть собрался,грамотей.

Comment: Серьёзно,зачем вы здесь пишете,если на конкретный вопрос не хотите дать конкретный ответ? Зачем мне ответ в стиле "Я знаю ,но не скажу".

Comment: Затем, что надоела лбов уму разуму учить у себя...

Comment: Не надо противоречить себе:надоелА-проходи мимо,грамотей.

Answer (score 3):

То что описано, не совсем одновременная работа, сначала с одной веткой что то делается, потом с другой.

```
git clone ...
git checkout -b origin/HEAD A # создает ветку для задания А
git commit # A1
git commit # A2
git commit # A3
git checkout -b origin/HEAD B
git commit # B1
git commit # B2
git commit # B3
```

Comment: Я ,как начинающий ,сделал клон .Потом делал коммиты и пушы. Потом сделал бранч ,переключился на него и делал коммиты и пушы на него.Когда зашёл на сайт- увидел ,что все изменения были везде - и на мастерс и на новом бранче.Это не то ,что я хотел.А чем чекаут отличается от бранч?

Comment: branch - создает ветку, checkout - переводит в эту ветку для работы. Если Вы работаете с каким-то GUI для git, то нужно проверить, что commit делается в нужной ветке.

Comment: Я сделал бранч после А1,А2 и А3- назовём его НБ.Потом делал коммиты на него В1 и В2.В итоге у меня ветка НБ,где и коммиты А1-А3 и В1,В2.А мне нужно только В1,В2.И потом сделать два пул реквеста с только А и только В.

Comment: Миша дал неполный ответ,у меня там ещё А4 и два пул реквеста.

Comment: Сделайте ветку до коммитов A1,A2 и А3.

Comment: У Миши был хороший формат ответа,но незаконченный.Нельзя ли дать простой ответ в командах , без общих фраз.
Итак,поправьте меня:

git clone..

git commit A1

git push

git commit A2

git push 

git commit A3

git push

git branch NEW_BRANCH

git checkout NEW_BRANCH

git commit B1

git push

git commit B2

git push

git commit B3

git push

git checkout master

git commit A4

git push

иду на сайт чтобы сделать pull request c ветки master коммитов А1 А2 А3 A4
и pull request c ветки NEW_BRANCH коммитов B1 B2 B3.
Где ошибки?

Answer (score 3):

Что делали вы:

1. вы работаете в ветке А (вершина А0).
       Делаете коммиты А1, А2, А3.
       Пушите (теперь вершина А3)
2. затем создаете ветку от текущей В.
       Её вершиной будет А3, т.к. вы ушли от текущей.
3. Делаете коммиты В1, В2, В3.
       Пушите. Вершиной будет В3.

Если посмотреть все сверху вниз, то будет
В3, В2, В1,А3,А2,А1.

Нужно было делать так:

1. Заранее создать две ветки из вершины А0, т.е. до каких либо коммитов
2. После переключения могли просто откатить ветку В, до нужной вам вершине.

Комманды:

1. Откатиться: git reset --hard <SHA коммита на который откатываетесь>
2. Просмотреть вершины: git log

Comment: Совсем забыл, есть еще замечательная комманда
cherry-pick, с ее помощью можно пикать коммиты из одной ветки в другую